# Why `find` likes `stat` or `fstat` so much?

Tags: linux, find, stat

I'm trying to make `/usr/bin/find` to show something meaningful without doing any sort of `stat`, with no useful results so far. If I forcefully inhibit `stat`, find stops descending into subdirectories at all.

As manual page of `getdents` syscall say, there is `d_type` field there, so `find` should already have some information necessary for decisions.

Why need to for `stat` regardless of `-L`, `-H` or whatever options.

Comment: What find implementation? what command line?

Comment: With gnu find, the use of `d_type` is a compile-time option.  `find --version` will tell you if your version was compiled with it.

Comment: @NateEldredge `Features enabled: D_TYPE O_NOFOLLOW(enabled) LEAF_OPTIMISATION FTS() CBO(level=0)`

Comment: Ok, so this is gnu find.  What options are you passing to it?

Comment: No options whatsoever. Also tried with `-H` and `-L`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the source, Luke!

In the GNU `find` source (I'm looking at version 4.2.2), the code that traverses directory trees is in `gnulib/lib/fts.c`.  At line 1123 there is the following comment:

> Record what fts_read will have to do with this
>                              entry. In many cases, it will simply fts_stat it,
>                              but we can take advantage of any d_type information
>                              to optimize away the unnecessary stat calls.  I.e.,
>                              if FTS_NOSTAT is in effect and we're not following
>                              symlinks (FTS_PHYSICAL) and d_type indicates this
>                              is *not* a directory, then we won't have to stat it
>                              at all.  If it *is* a directory, then (currently)
>                              we stat it regardless, in order to get device and
>                              inode numbers.  Some day we might optimize that
>                              away, too, for directories where d_ino is known to
>                              be valid.

So they have thought of the optimization you describe, but it is not implemented.

Comment: Direct source link, for others who want to check if `fts.c` improves in this regard: https://github.com/coreutils/gnulib/blob/8f3e5e5046055bc00151fe28b50ac438270e23b3/lib/fts.c#L1509-L1513

Comment: I have checked that `findutils` `v4.5.17`, the last release before `--disable-fts` was removed, also does the unnecessary `stat()` on directories; in fact, it even `fchdir()`s into each directory, which is even slower. Reading its source code for 5 minutes, I didn't find an option combination that would disable the stat in this old version.

Answer (score 2):

The cited manual page for [getdents](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getdents.2.html) is Linux-specific, and does not apply to all filesystem types (for instance, the manual page does not mention [`procfs`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) or [`nfs`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/nfs.5.html)), while GNU [find](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html) is not platform-specific (its manual page mentions SELinux, which is arguably a useful feature to take into account).  It *could* be optimized for this special case as well.

Even if the feature is available, the manual page recommends:

> All applications must properly handle a return of ***`DT_UNKNOWN`***.

That is, the information if available can be useful, but it is not guaranteed to be present.

With all of those drawbacks, the developers of `find` may not see the need for this optimization.  A motivated user could delve into the source code to see how to do this and propose a suitable ifdef'd change.

[@Nate Eldredge](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/56646/nate-eldredge) notes that someone *started* in this direction.  The `find` manual states in *[7.2 d_type Optimisation](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/d_005ftype-Optimisation.html)*

> When this feature is enabled, find takes advantage of the fact that on some systems readdir will return the type of a file in struct dirent.

The feature was [first mentioned](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/findutils.git/commit/?id=05e0f592d3f0572610e7177b35f15f4c25f801c4) in

```
2005-01-17  James Youngman  <jay@gnu.org>
    * configure.in, find/defs.h, find/find.c, find/parser.c, find/pred.c, find/tree.c, find/util.c:
    Implemented d_type optimisation but not working correctly, so currently disabled
```

Later, it was [revised to use gnulib](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/findutils.git/commit/?id=a3fbb31c1df79089d562042c0b64a9489c73625d) to support this:

```
2010-04-08  James Youngman  <jay@gnu.org>

    Adopt the use of the gnulib module d-type.
    * import-gnulib.config (modules): Import the d-type module.
    * configure.ac: Remove old struct dirent.d_type detection logic
    (since we now use the gnulib macro from the d-type module for
    this).
```

Version 4.2.2 is rather old (perhaps a typo), by the way: [4.2.3](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/findutils.git/commit/?id=85b257c424058db5f4edf8d3748602e8ca9426a6) dates from 2004, and is before these changelog entries.  The current release-tag in git is [4.5.14](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/findutils.git/tag/?id=v4.5.14) (mid-2014).

Regardless of the status of a `d_type` optimization, the developers are interested in reducing the number of calls to `stat`.  A note from [4.5.4](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/findutils.git/commit/NEWS?id=2bf001636e66789560ef1d2509c117f78b6cd06f) (2009-03-10) says for instance:

> The ftsfind executable also now avoids calling stat() functions to
>   discover the inode number of a file, if we already read this
>   information from the directory.  This does provide a speed-up, but
>   only for a restricted set of commands such as "find . -inum 4001".
>   This fix is listed below as bug #24342.

In summary: OP asked

> Why need to for stat regardless of -L, -H or whatever options.

The reason is that it is a special case which is troublesome to make it work seamlessly instead of `stat` for all of the scenarios where `find` might need this, and that it takes time to do this.

Comment: GNU find already does have support for 
`d_type` as a configure-time option.

Comment: So someone was motivated.  By the way, it helps to point out how long the feature has been there.

Comment: From the output of `find --version` it looks like D_TYPE is enabled. How do I start stat-less find with it?

Comment: If it's present and working, it's supposed to "just work".